# Batch File To Read And Modify Text File

Tags: file, batch-file, windows-xp, hosts

Okay, so basically, I have a whole list of links in a plain text Notepad file, each link on a seperate line. All I am wanting to do is to add a bit of text before each link, specifically: 127.0.0.1 and a couple of spaces.

So this...

```
somelink.com
```

becomes this...

```
127.0.0.1     somelink.com
```

By now you've probably already guessed that I am trying to edit the contents of a text file to make it useable as a HOSTS file in Windows.

So I am wanting some batch file code, executable in a .bat file, which basically reads a Notepad text file, and then add "127.0.0.1 " at the beginning of each line with text on it. I am guessing this is probably a very simple piece of code for someone with some knowledge of MS DOS and batch file code, but that most certainly isn't me, and the only batch files I have ever written have been with help like now.

Thanks for any and all help in advance with this, it really is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

read `HELP FOR` and then try this in a command prompt

```
  FOR /F "delims=" %a in (input.txt) do @echo 127.0.0.1   %a >>output.txt
```

here is some explanation and some considerations to extend it with a little more complete functionality and put it in a BAT file

1. FOR is the command to iterate over the lines of your input text file. Read microsoft documentation at http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx
2. `input.txt` is the text file that contains your list of domain names, it must reside in the current directory
3. `output.txt` will be the result file that will contain the list of domain names prefixed with 127.0.0.1, it will be created in the current directory
4. If you want to create a BAT file, you need to move the FOR command and edit it a little bit, changing the `%a` loop variable names to be `%%a`.
5. You can then place the BAT file either in the current directory, where your input resided and where the output will be created.
6. Alternativelly, you may place your BAT file, elsewhere. In that case, you need to invoke it with its full path.
7. Or you may even place it in a special directory (I have my own `C:\Program Files\CMD`) and add it in the PATH system variable. See here www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/path.mspx?mfr=true how you can change your PATH for your current session. And here ss64.com/nt/path.html you may find some explanation on how to make the PATH change permanent.
8. Also, you might be tempted to add some flexibility to your BAT file, instead of having constant `input.txt` and `output.txt` filename, replace them with `%1` and `%2` which represent the first and second command line parameters of your BAT file.
9. the user might then want to use files which contain blanks in their filenames. They might specify them surrounding the names with quotes `"`. In that case, you need to add some incantation `usebackq` in the FOR command for it to not break havoc when the user uses quotes.
10. Finally, you will need to decide what to do in case the output text file already exists, you migh want to consider prevent overwriting.

So putting all this pieces together, here is a short BAT file to get you started...

```
    @echo off
    if .%2==. goto help
    if not exist %1 goto helpno1
    if exist %2 goto helpalready2
    FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (%1) do @echo 127.0.0.1   %%a >>%2
    goto :eof
    :help
    echo you need to specify input and output text files
    goto :eof
    :helpno1
    echo %1 not found
    goto :eof
    :helpalready2
    echo %2 already exist
    goto :eof
```

welcome to BAT programming and enjoy!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say read HELP FOR - what is it and where can I read it? Thanks.

Comment: After following what you said, PA, I still didn't manage to get it working for some reason. :( Is there any editing I need to do to that code beforehand? Do I need to be changing any variable names or anything like that, or creating the files input.txt/output.txt? Please note that I'm a total newbie to batch file code, and therefore all of this that I am getting from you and posters below is simply being copy-and-pasted.

Comment: @Hashim change your %a to %%a if you are running it from a batch-file.

Comment: Thank you very much for the extended help, PA., it does help a lot. However, I am still having issues understanding what most of this code means. :$

I do understand small parts here and there, such as:
 
'goto help','goto helpno1', and 'helpalready2' - I understand that goto must be some sort of built-in function which tells CMD to go to a particular section at the bottom, when a condition is true. 

However, pretty much everything else I am having trouble with. If not too much trouble, please could you break each command down into tiny pieces for me to understand?

Comment: And I would prefer to use output.txt and input.txt, at elast for now, it saves me a lot of confusion in these early stages of just trying to grasp the code. Once again, thanks for your help.

Comment: Firstly, are `if not exist` and `if exist` built-in functions, much the same as goto? Or are they variables which are created? Please forgive me for my noobishness, the only kind of programming experience I have behind me is JavaScript really.

Comment: try `HELP GOTO` and `HELP IF`

Comment: Okay, after reading the HELP IF, I found that the snytax was `IF [NOT] EXIST` rather than what you put, `if not exist`. Are both the same - can both be used?

Comment: the square brackets [] mean optional. So it's either `IF EXIST` or `IF NOT EXIST`. I recommend you to read some book on programming BAT files and then get yourself wet trying and testing and debugging and having fun.

Comment: Tbh I'm not really wanting to get into batch file programming, if I had wanted I would have tried to get hold of a book. The only reason I am here is because I want to achieve something on my computer using a batch file, so I need the exact code to do that. At the same time though, I don't want to be someone who is happy to just copiy and paste - I like to actually understand the code I am copying and pasting, but at the same time, I don't think it's really worth going through an entire book on batch file programming just to do so, especially when most of my time is already taken up by work.

Comment: Okay, I'll post which parts of the code I'm having trouble understanding, working my way from top to bottom. Firstly, this: if .%2==. goto help. I understand the last part, goto help, fine, it's just the .%2==. I am have trouble understanding. What is that if command checking for? Am I right in assuming that == is an "equal to" sign?

Comment: Anyone? Still need help understanding this code. As I said, I don't want to be just taking it away, I want to understand what I am copying and pasting.

Answer (score 3):

here we go!

```
(
Set /p line1=
Set /p line2=
Set /p line3=
Set /p line4=
)<Filename.txt
echo 127.0.0.1    %line1%>Filename.txt
echo 127.0.0.1    %line2%>>Filename.txt
echo 127.0.0.1    %line3%>>Filename.txt
echo 127.0.0.1    %line4%>>Filename.txt
```

This will Read the first four lines of the text file, and then put in your stuff and each line back into the line it came from.
Have Fun!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to PA.'s answer, if you require a specific number of spaces, you can throw them into a variable and add it to the command as well.

```
  SET spaces=          # to the left is 10 spaces
  FOR /F "delims=" %a in (input.txt) do @echo 127.0.0.1%spaces%%a>>output.txt
```

So the output will be

```
127.0.0.1          somelink.com
```

Batch-File flavor:

```
  SET spaces=          # to the left is 10 spaces
  FOR /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do @echo 127.0.0.1%spaces%%%a>>output.txt
```

Comment: If the OP needs it in a batch file `%a` will need to be `%%a` :)

Comment: Of Course =D I'll add in a consideration for a batch file